# Storing PDF’s within SQL database using Flutter

Tags: flutter

In Flutter is it at all possible to store .PDF’s in a sql database on the device?

I currently have the database setup and working for strings and int’s, but can’t see how to store data blocks etc.

Many thanks.

Comment: if your pdf is a sequence of bytes then yes, you can store it using sqflite, but actually why not to keep it in a normal file system as separate files?

Comment: Thanks for your response, my plan is to keep the PDF’s stored within the apps data so that it doesn’t get deleted by accident.

Comment: you can still use it in app's file system, where do you think your sql database is stored? can you delete it by accident? for example use: https://pub.dev/documentation/path_provider/latest/